# Subset Sum with Floats

Tags: floating-point, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem, subset-sum

Consider that you have a set of floats, for instance

```
4.2  ; 2.6  ;  6.9  ;  1.1
```

And you need to determine if there exists a Subset whose sum is equal to 5.3, and if so, return this set.

All given numbers have always one decimal.

One way to do this is by brute force: generate all  combinations of the original set, and check each individually for its sum. However this is rather bad, and generally this sort of problem is tackled using dynamic programming --- indeed, this a special of the [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem).

My question is, since we are considering floats, how would you go about tackling this efficiently?

The standard dynamic programming approach does not seem to be a good candidate since it would require me to build a table accounting all possible *float* values from 0 up to the target number (5.3 in this example). Since we know that we always have one decimal point, I guess one can imagine such table:

```
     0 | 0.1 | 0.2 | ... | 5.3
4.2   
2.6
6.9
1.1
```

but I don't think this would scale well... (Here, 5.3 is just a value for the sake of simplicity, I don't have any info regarding target value bound in practice.)

Any thoughts on how to tackle this?

Comment: *One-decimal floats* is just a distraction.  Think integers.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Sure, I could use a HashMap to relate them, but my point is that following dynamic programming approach, I need to have as many columns as possible floats in between 0 and target value.. no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really need to reduce this to the integer case to get the results you probably want.

For the commonest floating point formats, those based on the IEEE 754 standard binary floating point, the answer is easy. There is no set of floats whose sum is 5.3. The only exactly representable values with one decimal place are those with 0 or 5 as the digit after the decimal point.

On the other hand, if you were to multiply every input by 10 and round to the nearest integer, you could solve it just as you would for integers.